# Modified FragmentStatePagerAdapter throws a NullPointerException on pre lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentstatepageradapter

I modified the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` a bit to get the ability of adding pages dynamically to the pager ([like on this blogpost here](http://androidyn.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/dynamic-fragmentstatepageradapter.html)).

Problem is, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` directly on the start on about 4 of 5 installations on pre-lollipop devices. Sometimes a installation just works and I can restart the app as often I want without getting any `NullPointerException`. Here is the stack trace:

```
12-04 13:23:46.084 16637-16637/abc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1020)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My adapter:

```
private class BannerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<WeakReference<Fragment>> registeredFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public BannerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
        this.add(BannerFragment.getInstance(0)); // <- this is crashing
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        WeakReference<Fragment> weakReference = registeredFragments.get(position);
        return weakReference.get();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return registeredFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void add(Fragment f){

        registeredFragments.add(new WeakReference<>(f));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int position){
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`this.add(BannerFragment.getInstance(0));` in the constructor lets it crash every time, I can't even catch the `NullPointerException` in a `try { } catch { }` block. 
The line just adds a first page with a title, all pages after that are loaded dynamically from the web. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: shouldn't you use registeredFragment.add(BannerFragment.getInstance(0));

Comment: It's the same. I'm just calling a function in the pager which is calling registeredFragment.add(BannerFragment.getInstance(0));, getting the same error with both methods.

Comment: can you show the BannerFragment class because it seems like we're not getting an instance from the Fragment itself hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: BannerFragment is good, I'll checked all that stuff with if (instance != null) ... and he keeps doing all of it until the fragment is actually added. I fixed it for now with adding the first banner page a bit later and it works, not a nice fix, but fine for now. Seems something isn't instantiated directly after creating the adapter.